# R' Herschel Schachter on Female Dayanim

Tags: women, beit-din-court

R' Saul Berman was a scholar in residence at Harvard Hillel this past Shabbat Zachor (28 Feb 2015). During se'udah shelishit, in response to a query which dealt with his talk after shacharit, he said that about 20 years ago, R' Herschel Schachter had made a remark about the likelihood of having female dayanim within the foreseeable future.

What did R' Schachter mean by this? From what I'm aware of, a woman cannot serve on a bit din. If so, how could he say that within the foreseeable future, we would see female dayanim?

Comment: This is the first in a planned series of questions based on R' Berman's recent visit to Harvard Hillel. Please bear with me, as my source is having been present at his talks.

Comment: Why didn't you ask your questions to R. Berman? He's very approachable

Comment: @Matt, we were running out of time at this point and he had to leave immediately after havdalah

Comment: @Matt, I got around to it over Shabbos.

Answer (score 3):

R' Berman was a scholar in residence at Harvard Hillel again this Shabbat and I asked him what R' Schachter had meant. It turns out that R' Schachter was referring to Orthodox dayanot and that although a female beit din may not be appointed, it may be accepted by communal authorities, in which case it becomes valid. Of course, this also relies on both parties being willing to go to a court of dayanot.

R' Berman concluded by mentioning that classically speaking, there was no historical opposition to learned women paskening or judging cases until it started to become more of a reality.

---

Source: R' Saul Berman שליט”א

Comment: @DoubleAA, is my sourcing sufficient? I asked R' Berman over Shabbos and I wasn't sure that were I to request mekorot beyond what I have, that I would have recalled them.

Comment: Sufficient for what? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3684/759

Comment: I heard in one of Rav Schacters shuurim on Chullin that the Rav was against women holding such an authority because we pasken that they cannot do shechita because it was a communal postion and they were like second to the Rabbi,it seemed quite clear that Rav Schacter would not against his Rebbe and support such an idea

Comment: Read his word's here :https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%252011%2520Schachter.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjS_8-j9ZvLAhUFXB4KHSLVDu0QFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNEkBMFiuuqqY84PqOBJ8p-PY-yvhw&sig2=9B6b6sufil-iI4ln2AdYoA

Comment: There are certainly plenty of places in the Talmud in which we see women correcting or providing mesora for men (Beruriah and being the most famous example). It doesn't entirely surprise me - after all, Devorah seems to act just like Shmuel does vis a vis being a dayan (Tomer Devorah, etc.) and communal (NOT congregational) leader. Considering these, one wonders when this switch took place...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, probably during the time of the Acharonim.

Answer (score 2):

Not having been present at that shiur (nor by any by Rav Schachter on related topics), it's hard to say *precisely* what might have been meant...but I'll hazard a guess.

Nowhere in your question did you mention that Rav Schachter would *support* female dayanim, which I think may be the point you're confusing. Unless something in the context of the shiur you heard tells you otherwise, I'd assume that Rav Schachter's prediction dealt with the actions of certain groups of Jews who don't identify as strictly Orthodox -- perhaps his intent was that those groups would start making use of female dayanim, even though that may run counter to normative halacha.

Comment: I don't think so. Based on the context (which I tried to convey as closely as possible to how I remember it) it seemed like RH"Sch was talking **within** the context of the Orthodox (or rather, orthoprax) world, rather than in the Conservative world. In his shiur earlier, R' Berman had mentioned this without an attribution as something in the context of orthodoxy. While I may misrecall, this is how I interpreted it.

Comment: As I said, you have context, and I don't...though I think you might want to rethink that, as I don't think it makes much sense (which, I understand, is what prompted your question).

Comment: Exactly! How can we have female dayanim in an Orthodox context?! Not even R' Avi Weiss has gone that far, and his Maharat program is certainly not standard. The fact that a reliable rav cites another saying something of this nature means that he presumably has a reshut to do so and a valid source.

Comment: Shokhet, you still at the Mir?

Comment: Yes [15 character]